# IEEE 4 machine system: Need help in computing the bus admittance matrix

Tags: power, current, matlab, system, matrix

I need help in computing the bus admittance matrix for the following Kundur's 4 machine 2 area system:

[image]

```
%% branch data
%      From(Bus) to(bus) r(p.u)  x(p.u) b(total charging line susceptance)         

mpc.branch =  [1    2     0.0025    0.025    0.00175*25;
           2    5     0.0010    0.010    0.00175*10;          
           5    6     0.0220    0.220    0.00175*10;
           3    4     0.0025    0.025    0.00175*25;   
           4    6     0.0010    0.010    0.00175*10];

%%Bus       V           phase       P gen       Q gen       P load   Q load      
           [p.u.]      [rad]       [p.u.]      [p.u.]      [p.u.]   [p.u.]  

Bus 01      1.03        0.86019     7.4911      0.71811     0           0          

Bus 02      1.01        0.68099     2.9291      1.3674      0           0          

Bus 03      1.03       -0.11868     6.2548      0.63815     0           0          

Bus 04      1.01       -0.26796     5.258       1.0209      0           0          

Bus 05      0.99698     0.57945     0           0           6.2855     -1.6        

Bus 06      0.9973     -0.3808      0           0           14.806     -2.6 

%% State-variables of the generators
Power angle(rad): 
delta_Syn_1=1.7281, delta_Syn_2=1.089,
delta_Syn_3=0.66592, delta_Syn_4=0.41743    

Angular frequency (p.u): 1 represents the steady-state
omega_Syn_1=1, omega_Syn_2=1, omega_Syn_3=1, omega_Syn_4=1          

Transient voltage: q axis—e1q, and d axis—e1d.
e1q_Syn_1=0.86696, e1d_Syn_1=0.64857, 
e1q_Syn_2=1.0075,  e1d_Syn_2=0.33055,    
e1q_Syn_3=0.88761, e1d_Syn_3=0.6004,     
e1q_Syn_4=0.91878, e1d_Syn_4=0.52742
```

The matrix I computed:

```
Yt =[3.9604-39.5821i -3.9604 +39.6040i  0   0;
-3.9604+39.6040i  10.2978-42.5695i  0   0.4488 + 4.1550i;
0    0   3.9604-39.5821i  -3.9604+39.6040i;
0    0.4488+4.1550i  -3.9604 +39.6040i  18.1924 -43.2853i]
```

The generater currents *It* calculated from *It=Yt*Ut* fails to satisfy the power generation. Can anyone point out if the computation of *Yt* is incorrect, or the power flow analysis is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your Y-bus matrix needs to have dimension 6x6. 
If you're using matlab to determine the Ybus matrix, I'd suggest following these steps:

1. Calculate admittance vector Y at each line:

   ```
   Y = 1./(R+iX)
   ```
2. Convert the Y vector into a diagonal matrix

   ```
   Yd = diag(Y).
   ```
3. Determine the connection/incidence matrix A which is a n(branch)xn(bus) matrix. From your branch matrix, it should be

   ```
   A = [1 -1 0 0 0 0; 0 1 0 0 -1 0 ; 0 0 0 0 1 -1; 0 0 1 -1 0 0; 0 0 0 1 0 -1] 
   Y = A' * Yd * A
   ```
4. Add the line susceptance to diagonal elements. You could use the below code for this part.

   ```
   for jk  = 1:nbus
       j   = Bus(jk);
       fl  = find(Fbus == j); 
       if length(fl)~=0
           for jj=1:length(fl) 
               Y(j,j)=Y(j,j)+1j*B(fl(jj))/2
           end
       end
       tl  = find(Tbus == j);
       if length(tl)~=0
           for jj=1:length(tl) 
               Y(j,j)=Y(j,j)+1j*B(tl(jj))/2
           end
       end
   end
   ```